# C - Is there a way to put variables inside single or double quotation marks in an if statement?

Tags: c, string, variables, if-statement

I'm having issues with comparing a character with a string inside an if statement.
I'm trying to make a not-too-complicated version of Hangman and I'm stuck on this part.
I've tried everything from `strcmp()` and `strchr()` and others, but nothing seems to work.

```
#include<stdio.h>  
#include<string.h> 

int main() {  
    int length, i;
    int size=3;
    char word[size]="car";
    char letter;
    //const char* word="car";
    //const char* letter;
    int guess;
    length=strlen(word);

printf("The given word has %d letters.\n", length);
//do {
    guess=0;
    printf("Enter a letter:");
    scanf("%c", &letter);
    for (i=0; i<length; i++) {
        if (letter== 'word[i]' && guess==0) {
            guess=1;
        }
        /*if (strchr(letter, word[i])!=NULL && guess==0) {
            guess=1;
        }*/
    }
    if (guess=1) {
        printf("Correct letter.\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Wrong letter.\n");
    }
//} while ();
}
```

I'm out of ideas as to what to do and I've searched everywhere as to what I could do. I do not want to use an already-made Hangman game as I'm trying to teach myself as a beginner and because those codes are way too complicated for my simple mind.

I'm trying to keep my code simple, and as can be seen in my code above, everything is set up quite simply. I am still a long way from finishing the code, but I just want to find a solution to this problem before I continue.

Thanks!

Comment: `char word[3]="car";` - Uh, oh! That won't work. You need 4 chars to store the string "car". Remember you need one extra char for the null terminator.

Comment: are you sure your code works ? O_o , i'm not , look at this line `letter== 'word[i]'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `word[i]` and `letter` are of type `char`, so just compare them.

```
if (letter==word[i] && guess==0) {
```

Other errors:

```
scanf("%c", &letter);
```

You need a leading space at the start of the pattern to eat any whitespace, otherwise you'll end up reading a newline character.

```
scanf(" %c", &letter);
```

Also:

```
if (guess=1) {
```

This is an assignment, not a comparison.  You want:

```
if (guess==1) {
```

Also:

```
int size=3;
char word[size]="car";
```

The array is not big enough, since you don't have room for a null termination character.  In this case, just omit the size and the compiler will use the correct value.

```
char word[]="car";
```